# Firebase Email-Password Authentication using Kotlin in Web Front-End

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-frontend

I am trying to implement **Firebase Email-Password Authentication** using **Kotlin** in **Web Front-End**. But I think we can't do it using **Kotlin** as **Firebase Authentication** for **Web** only supports **JS** as per the examples I have seen.

So, my first question is: Can we implement it using **Kotlin**?

If not then, how can we call **JS function** from **Kotlin** within a **Kotlin** file and vice-versa?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and Kotlin can easily interoperate. Here I'll provide some excerpts from official documentation as well as links to that documentation.

[**Calling Kotlin code from JS**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html)

> To prevent spoiling the global object, Kotlin creates an object that
> contains all Kotlin declarations from the current module. So if you
> name your module as myModule, all declarations are available to
> JavaScript via myModule object. For example:
>
> `fun foo() = "Hello"`
> Can be called from JavaScript like this:
> `alert(myModule.foo());`

**[Calling JS code from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html)**

> To tell Kotlin that a certain declaration is written in pure
> JavaScript, you should mark it with external modifier. When the
> compiler sees such a declaration, it assumes that the implementation
> for the corresponding class, function or property is provided by the
> developer.

I will add here that external function can be provided not necessarily by developer themselves - it can be something that already exist in this environment - like browser API.